# Similar proposals to the Muggle Protection Act?

Tags: harry-potter, laws

In the book Chamber of Secrets there are references to the Muggle Protection Act proposed by Arthur Weasley, aimed to protect the non-magic population against harmful or cursed artifacts made or possessed by wizards who wish to do them harm.

Were in the other books any reference to similar official proposals aiming to improve the circumstances of the 'weaker' minorities in the wizarding world (for example werewolves, centaurs or goblins) or any effort to try to cancel the discriminating legislation against them by those members of the Order of Phoenix who were Ministry of Magic employees or by Dumbledore, as the member of`the Wizenmagot? Or was there at least any public statement,  quoted in the wizarding newspapers/radio of any Order member on the subject?

Comment: Not really. The magical world is full of stigma and discrimination. Though most of the legal stuff against other species lay in designating them as 'beasts', which limited a creature'screature' s rights somewhat. Non-humans also aren't allowed to hold wands.

Comment: Does SPEW count?

Comment: @Mithrandir i am looking for something a bit more official

Comment: @TheDarkLord Wouldn't it be logical that Kinsley or Dumbledore seeing the struggles of their fellow order member, Lupin try to do something through official channels?  Or Dumbledore,  to win over the minorities, so they wouldn't be tempted by the DE?

Comment: Dumbledore is only one man. "I have no power to make other men see the truth, or to overrule the Minister for Magic..."

Comment: @TheDarkLord but it's curious that a minor ministry worker like Arthur did suceed to change things with his Muggle Protection Act

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Over the years, there have been several proposals for minorities in the Wizarding world, (namely Ghosts, Squibs, Muggles, House-elves, Trolls, and Goblins), but none seem to have been very successful.

- **Protest Floats** - c.1815

  > Question 6 out of 15
  >   Match the Minister for Magic with the major upheaval of his/her term in office, dates of which are marked.
  >   Part 2 out of 6
  >   Grogan Stump (1811 - 1819)
  >   ☐ Attempted assassination by centaur
  >   ☐ Pureblood riots during Squib Rights marches
  >   ☐ Several of the oldest Wizengamot wizards walk out in protest at Minister's appointment
  >   ☐ Persistent denial of notorious Dark wizard's existence forces Minister's resignation after notorious Dark wizard appears at the Ministry of Magic
  >   **☐ Ghost demonstrations at the Ministry of Magic ("protest floats")**
  >   ☐ A night of large-scale breaches of the International Wizarding Statute of Secrecy
  >   <sub>W.O.M.B.A.T. - Grade Three - Question 6</sub>
- **Squib Rights marches** - c.1968

  > Question 6 out of 15
  >   Match the Minister for Magic with the major upheaval of his/her term in office, dates of which are marked.
  >   Part 4 out of 6
  >   Nobby Leach (1962 - 1968)
  >   ☐ Attempted assassination by centaur
  >   **☐ Pureblood riots during Squib Rights marches**
  >   ☐ Several of the oldest Wizengamot wizards walk out in protest at Minister's appointment
  >   ☐ Persistent denial of notorious Dark wizard's existence forces Minister's resignation after notorious Dark wizard appears at the Ministry of Magic
  >   ☐ Ghost demonstrations at the Ministry of Magic ("protest floats")
  >   ☐ A night of large-scale breaches of the International Wizarding Statute of Secrecy
  >   <sub>W.O.M.B.A.T. - Grade Three - Question 6</sub>
  >
  > Eugenia Jenkins
  >   1968 - 1975
  >   Jenkins dealt competently with pure-blood riots during Squib Rights marches in the late sixties, but was soon confronted with the first rise of Lord Voldemort. Jenkins was soon ousted from office as inadequate to the challenge.
  >   <sub>[Pottermore - Ministers for Magic](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic)</sub>
- **Appeal Against House-Elf Slavery** - c.1973

  > Question 3 out of 15
  >   Choose the Ministry of Magic decision that, in your estimation, had the MOST DAMAGING effect on present day wizarding life.
  >   ☐ The creation of the International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy in 1692.
  >   ☐ The defeat of the Appeal Against House-Elf Slavery in 1973.
  >   ☐ The drive into hiding of the surviving giants in the early 1980s.
  >   ☐ The 1865 decision to leave full control of Gringotts in goblin hands.
  >   ☐ The Wand Ban of 1631, which forbade Non-Human Magical Beings to carry wands.
  >   <sub>W.O.M.B.A.T. - Grade Three - Question 3</sub>
- **Muggle Protection Act** - c.1992

  > “I have not been visited yet. The name Malfoy still commands a certain respect, yet the Ministry grows ever more meddlesome. There are rumors about a new Muggle Protection Act — no doubt that flea-bitten, Muggle-loving fool Arthur Weasley is behind it and as you see, certain of these poisons might make it appear —”
  >   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets - Chapter Four</sub>
  >
  > “Weasley has brought the Ministry into disrepute,” Mr. Malfoy told our reporter. “He is clearly unfit to draw up our laws and his ridiculous Muggle Protection Act should be scrapped immediately.”
  >   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets - Chapter Twelve</sub>
  >
  > “And imagine,” Dumbledore went on, “what might have happened then. . . . The Weasleys are one of our most prominent pure-blood families. Imagine the effect on Arthur Weasley and his Muggle Protection Act, if his own daughter was discovered attacking and killing Muggle-borns. . . . Very fortunate the diary was discovered, and Riddle’s memories wiped from it. Who knows what the consequences might have been otherwise. . . .”
  >   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets - Chapter Eighteen</sub>
- **Troll Rights Movement** - c.1993

  > Miss Heliotrope Willis, leader of the Troll Rights Movement, spoke defiantly through Lawlson’s abandoned megaphone of the trolls’ essentially peace-loving nature."
  >   <sub>The Daily Prophet #2 - *Troll Rights Movement Out of Control*</sub>
- **Bill of Goblin Rights** - c.1993

  > [paraphrased] Ministry of Magic representatives were meeting a delegation from the goblin pressure group B.O.G. (Brotherhood of Goblins) in Chipping Clodbury, in an effort to reach agreement on a new Bill of Goblin Rights.
  >   <sub>The Daily Prophet #3 - *Goblin Riots Erupt in Chipping Clodbury*</sub>

Additionally, while there is no indication of any official statements/movements, the following two WOMBAT questions indicate that there was some public support for minority rights.

> Question 5 out of 17
>   Which of the following wizarding laws, in your view, stands in most urgent need of change?
>   ☐ The detection of underage magic in all-magic households (currently impossible)
>   ☐ The ban of goblin possession of wands (ought to be lifted)
>   ☐ The re-classification of centaurs and merpeople (ought to take their views into account)
>   ☐ The guidelines on house-elf welfare (need to be enforced)
>   ☐ Definitions of 'Muggle-baiting' (need to be made less stringent)
>   <sub>W.O.M.B.A.T. - Grade One - Question 5</sub>
>
> Question 12 out of 18
>   What change would 18% of wizards like to see to the requirements for membership of the Wizengamot? (source: Ministry of Magic poll)
>   ☐ Average age lowered from 87
>   ☐ Proof of pure-blood status
>   ☐ Maximum of three years in post
>   ☐ Goblin representation
>   <sub>W.O.M.B.A.T. - Grade Two - Question 12</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In the third issue of the real life Daily Prophet, they mention the [Bill of Goblin Rights](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/bill-of-goblin-rights/). And in the second issue, there's the [Troll rights movement](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/troll-rights-movement/).

(source: HP Lexicon)

Comment: Interesting, take +1, though i dont think Helitrope Willis or the goblins of B.O.G were order members

Comment: Trolls have rights. */smiles earnestly*